# Why a test with function called from another function in the mocked class fail?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have an issue with testing a pretty simple of javascript code using jest. So I post the code:

Foo.js

```
export class Foo {

   constructor() {

   }

   someFn() {

        this.internalFn();
   }

   internalFn() {

   }
}
```

Foo.spec.js

```
    jest.mock('../src/foo');

    import {Foo} from '../src/foo';

    describe('Foo', () => {

        it ('test foo', () => {

            const foo = new Foo();

            foo.someFn();

            expect(foo.someFn.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
            expect(foo.internalFn.mock.calls.length).toBe(1); // why received 0 ???
        })
    })
```

Why second expect fail? foo.internalFn is called from foo.someFn.

Comment: Try to do `this.someFn= this.someFn.bind(this);` in the constructor and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @connexo: Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mock function will actually not do anything (except for counting how often it was called, etc.)

That's why your `internalFn()` will bever be called, when you mock the function `someFn()`.

// EDIT: Just some clarifications

When you unit test your software you want to test it modular and isolated.
Functions should be able to work on their own even when they're called internally by other functions.

When you want to test the function `someFn()` you have to mock `internalFn()`, because you want to check if `internalFn()` was actually called by calling `someFn()`.

If you want to to test anything else that will call `someFn()` you have to mock that instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I misunderstood the idea of unit testing.